# Cassandra server starts in active(exited) state and not able to connect

Tags: database, ubuntu, cassandra, vagrant, virtual-machine

I've installed Cassandra database version 3.11.4 in my vagrant machine(Ubuntu xenial, 10 Gb disk space) from Debian packages by following the steps provided in [Cassandra installation page](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html).

But when I check the Cassandra running status with the command

> sudo service cassandra status

it shows the output as

> root@user:/home/vagrant# sudo service cassandra status
>
> cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured
>   data    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-02-20 07:23:46 UTC;
>   59min ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   Process: 1375 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>       Tasks: 0    Memory: 0B
>         CPU: 0

I'm also adding system.log file. Please help me to fix the issue. 
Thanks in advance

```
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:57,262 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,163 Config.java:496 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=null; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@1198b989; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_materialized_views=true; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=null; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=true; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=localhost; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=127.0.0.1}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@7ff95560; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,164 DatabaseDescriptor.java:373 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,164 DatabaseDescriptor.java:431 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 120MB
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,165 DatabaseDescriptor.java:435 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 120MB
WARN  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,235 DatabaseDescriptor.java:480 - Small commitlog volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog; setting commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 2465.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,238 DatabaseDescriptor.java:507 - Small cdc volume detected at /var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw; setting cdc_total_space_in_mb to 1232.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,600 DatabaseDescriptor.java:556 - Only 6.920GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,775 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:23:59,776 DatabaseDescriptor.java:735 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,289 JMXServerUtils.java:246 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,379 CassandraDaemon.java:476 - Hostname: migrator
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,380 CassandraDaemon.java:483 - JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_201
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,383 CassandraDaemon.java:484 - Heap size: 483.750MiB/483.750MiB
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,384 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 5025856(4908K) committed = 5046272(4928K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,386 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 18332464(17902K) committed = 19005440(18560K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,387 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2242016(2189K) committed = 2490368(2432K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,388 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 103284736(100864K) used = 82708368(80769K) committed = 103284736(100864K) max = 103284736(100864K)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,390 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 12845056(12544K) used = 0(0K) committed = 12845056(12544K) max = 12845056(12544K)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,390 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 391118848(381952K) used = 0(0K) committed = 391118848(381952K) max = 391118848(381952K)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,391 CassandraDaemon.java:491 - Classpath: /etc/cassandra:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/caffeine-2.2.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrent-trees-2.4.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-18.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/hppc-0.5.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/javax.inject.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jctools-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jflex-1.6.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jna-4.2.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/joda-time-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jstackjunit-0.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-3.1.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-logback-3.1.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ohc-core-0.4.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/ohc-core-j8-0.4.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-base-3.0.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config3-3.0.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/sigar-1.6.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snowball-stemmer-1.3.0.581.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-3.11.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar::/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:00,392 CassandraDaemon.java:493 - JVM Arguments: [-Xloggc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log, -ea, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xss256k, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:-UseBiasedLocking, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:+ResizeTLAB, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled, -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10, -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M, -Xms495M, -Xmx495M, -Xmn123M, -XX:+UseCondCardMark, -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/cassandra/hotspot_compiler, -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password, -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra, -Dcassandra.storagedir=/var/lib/cassandra, -Dcassandra-pidfile=/var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/cassandra/java_1550647426.hprof, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1550647426.log]
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:01,439 NativeLibrary.java:174 - JNA mlockall successful
WARN  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:01,440 StartupChecks.java:136 - jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
WARN  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:01,440 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:01,460 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
WARN  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:01,588 SigarLibrary.java:174 - Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : true,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : false
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:02,638 QueryProcessor.java:116 - Initialized prepared statement caches with 10 MB (native) and 10 MB (Thrift)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:04,271 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.IndexInfo
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:06,444 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.batches
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:06,470 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.paxos
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:06,529 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.local
INFO  [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2019-02-20 07:24:07,003 BufferPool.java:230 - Global buffer pool is enabled, when pool is exhausted (max is 120.000MiB) it will allocate on heap
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:08,763 CacheService.java:100 - Initializing key cache with capacity of 24 MBs.
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:08,844 CacheService.java:122 - Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:08,847 CacheService.java:151 - Initializing counter cache with capacity of 12 MBs
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:08,849 CacheService.java:162 - Scheduling counter cache save to every 7200 seconds (going to save all keys).
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,298 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.peers
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,325 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.peer_events
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,345 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.range_xfers
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,378 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.compaction_history
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,444 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.sstable_activity
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,655 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.size_estimates
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,748 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.available_ranges
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,771 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.transferred_ranges
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,779 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.views_builds_in_progress
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,791 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.built_views
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,804 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.hints
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,824 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.batchlog
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,847 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.prepared_statements
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,864 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.schema_keyspaces
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,881 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.schema_columnfamilies
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,900 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.schema_columns
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,929 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.schema_triggers
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,949 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.schema_usertypes
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:09,971 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.schema_functions
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:10,013 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system.schema_aggregates
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:10,015 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:10,948 ApproximateTime.java:44 - Scheduling approximate time-check task with a precision of 10 milliseconds
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:11,367 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.keyspaces
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:11,640 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.tables
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:11,907 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.columns
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:12,027 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.triggers
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:12,069 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.dropped_columns
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:12,100 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.views
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:12,164 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.types
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:12,272 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.functions
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:12,337 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.aggregates
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:12,372 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_schema.indexes
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:12,408 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_schema as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:14,513 StorageService.java:619 - Populating token metadata from system tables
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:14,793 StorageService.java:626 - Token metadata: Normal Tokens:
localhost/127.0.0.1:[]

INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:16,589 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_distributed.parent_repair_history
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:16,722 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_distributed.repair_history
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:16,745 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_distributed.view_build_status
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:16,757 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_distributed as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:16,797 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_auth.resource_role_permissons_index
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:16,822 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_auth.role_members
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:16,847 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_auth.role_permissions
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:16,867 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_auth.roles
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:17,145 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_auth as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:17,266 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_traces.events
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:17,325 ColumnFamilyStore.java:430 - Initializing system_traces.sessions
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:17,338 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_traces as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] 2019-02-20 07:24:17,436 AutoSavingCache.java:174 - Completed loading (66 ms; 12 keys) KeyCache cache
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:17,853 CommitLog.java:147 - Replaying /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1550645815336.log, /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-6-1550645815337.log
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:17,983 CommitLogReader.java:105 - Skipping playback of empty log: CommitLog-6-1550645815337.log
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:21,077 CommitLog.java:149 - Log replay complete, 86 replayed mutations
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:21,172 StorageService.java:619 - Populating token metadata from system tables
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:21,385 StorageService.java:626 - Token metadata: Normal Tokens:


INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:22,451 QueryProcessor.java:163 - Preloaded 0 prepared statements
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:22,483 StorageService.java:637 - Cassandra version: 3.11.4
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:22,494 StorageService.java:638 - Thrift API version: 20.1.0
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:22,494 StorageService.java:639 - CQL supported versions: 3.4.4 (default: 3.4.4)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:22,494 StorageService.java:641 - Native protocol supported versions: 3/v3, 4/v4, 5/v5-beta (default: 4/v4)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:23,321 IndexSummaryManager.java:80 - Initializing index summary manager with a memory pool size of 24 MB and a resize interval of 60 minutes
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:24,083 MessagingService.java:750 - Starting Messaging Service on localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 (lo)
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:24,420 StorageService.java:569 - Unable to gossip with any peers but continuing anyway since node is in its own seed list
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:24,531 StorageService.java:723 - Loading persisted ring state
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:24,532 StorageService.java:841 - Starting up server gossip
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:24,945 TokenMetadata.java:497 - Updating topology for localhost/127.0.0.1
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:25,130 TokenMetadata.java:497 - Updating topology for localhost/127.0.0.1
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:26,462 StorageService.java:1007 - Using saved tokens [-1007467607859164593, -1007934199144625205, -1018999848336560252, -1030396177807764803, -1043365409693018005, -1049817058012774376, -1092962265553640094, -1429282308415751755, -1459050278465189758, -1527728474738074599, -1533220906790540644, -1557539603122693015, -1578008743401332639, -1602973962885241941, -1802423746402796021, -2112502197419723161, -2120893358715608467, -2176858411212021558, -220651306545106358, -240113255605750199, -2411571256889622262, -2569648811396915868, -2698651926292877768, -2700703401507465003, -2701853250394115762, -2820199166558797941, -2929352019240725643, -2937336413003207422, -3101714233424075380, -3127727803887534370, -3196794834834925627, -3227994255320799434, -3270746068568282454, -3314202337093651886, -3425085181507791832, -3506641527536693107, -3549961973229903491, -3585649378017823595, -360426144910287266, -3746004757228086000, -3806201517872901694, -3904737273914387711, -3988499654634333522, -4063279648549086875, -4150384313401171671, -4189682792126004616, -4214146758301958882, -4248139642179272552, -4287679030751952129, -4365214015718408293, -4366828585465550086, -4509848762484718789, -4579673195919763910, -4607658223839239091, -4690901165353401992, -4692497254570881761, -4846998530020073261, -5017425396154304421, -5194819025458911818, -534431793147599859, -5368421802650728969, -5387389327812935308, -5452541052766935114, -5460010568281958884, -5477590214385634258, -5491893940186071696, -5555898270242002622, -5562225891180582495, -559341538746846534, -5610128270977148894, -5619032908345950988, -5687922264718378899, -5711399979315230201, -574613324487489089, -5771613291788658889, -5796649227952238425, -5960631136564968332, -6013315378277248915, -6107910328074590574, -6111292210156333228, -6165594152994405451, -6206691164592136258, -6247517655587191718, -6249364899164729559, -6406751486327192128, -6465636158235013440, -6526427284468413087, -655314985636271882, -6565064144155571955, -658649521874344501, -6730229568790784363, -674438580333406212, -6752000091226987527, -6961156362051232859, -7161088496842552203, -717100516264611207, -7283389154629699725, -7305165759874792536, -740706637048900417, -747578280959431309, -7561115761497443040, -7631480427627283557, -7785765337253991590, -7817355515700878347, -7932668539204917064, -79748236843997883, -8030826623001568685, -8097583382125436987, -8151002585997858308, -815385153281766807, -8170959081306191793, -8195226205829680269, -8244505530312628382, -8343797865837951666, -8428493983896612517, -8452995896614076057, -8472004597122248756, -8566816190042740342, -859170131260265840, -8598043330877868454, -8631411262495325763, -8693023661891739480, -8714331036514941492, -8727627159966801405, -8918253523325490019, -9081930649990616347, -9149948015939089335, -9172559505395816305, -925966129162709809, 1074996252616687492, 1100657878048223635, 1115678627182593397, 1225928430917296099, 1275880643855301634, 1433923623947396487, 1591857751526821895, 1681045701501696141, 1908314795971847636, 1952416542400137502, 1995289914312190475, 2020766357191494685, 2053103367978894597, 2075042602764824445, 2096918083314218890, 2103507190816081963, 220328585602522001, 2266391907547167492, 2392041825261296341, 2466744758028467675, 251623253783874297, 2912519712693471432, 2966269308041289153, 3080034508146743328, 3081051756361870625, 309591856639766505, 3110265840179153321, 3186372874336721162, 3218562167620298696, 3239294054586676939, 3251795480286478531, 325704464346785103, 32932224396418879, 34955048964075138, 3644932525690523216, 364902760476343836, 3710427609746580987, 3828907701274450240, 3892243298952516642, 3969075483333075047, 4190800278610926433, 4284070133345650159, 4291700681525750970, 4325260813982617092, 4332437596033100514, 4428809948200958689, 4507015694616716996, 4576786043261858621, 459963853537341769, 4614464319686418828, 4744557194922537083, 4802675580955986606, 4811383184490420386, 4822174776848041654, 4865768516795420941, 4897608816145220554, 492059818216216572, 4946872744375531473, 4958889285771120878, 4975603592981939246, 5059762190063671220, 5108209637538814766, 5189797565043738958, 5247286766369579073, 5301291563641244180, 5437775651100394478, 5437847844608077888, 5461570024949655359, 5462709149055785555, 5502387848773932031, 5537601014997783841, 5648902796513431016, 5879990688129504646, 598893873436122469, 5990820530675475204, 6164924067047745264, 6171772673663015572, 6423696021177765703, 6450955647569675854, 654632485899975156, 655652086565082958, 6616301052762890877, 670437263941915393, 6710356106649145532, 6725412046000984630, 6741393895732650729, 6749816891667275024, 6762761628917940876, 679181306522095905, 6816709595278187482, 6895220645752998183, 6909278146648078227, 6987333547414388105, 717716498101047264, 7177494553017578080, 7216972242403046815, 7383646677548751546, 744928350997848395, 7467305351626340035, 7513036789923961370, 757992804635750976, 7618314511000290814, 7636814258540975452, 7673306216549775251, 7706127830150577604, 7774933360832604024, 7808762456481150553, 8094574353675886329, 8167380799528074821, 8234932664501189656, 8235584755109699907, 8246462194662038326, 8276383954150634903, 8425086555089117042, 8503877351502778565, 8542552479739272603, 8605937922997526982, 866897927532920711, 867302219897621670, 8699398036201793470, 8705072422533496933, 8948128754540066728, 8955606417773195882, 9050972603674582221, 9062321038571421601, 9123909835747275291, 931437471632719745]
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:26,601 StorageService.java:1483 - JOINING: Finish joining ring
INFO  [main] 2019-02-20 07:24:27,127 StorageService.java:2327 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
```

Comment: Are you using the JMX service URL - `service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi` to connect?

Comment: No. I'm not aware of that one. I try to start with `sudo service cassandra start command`. For some moments, it will show status active(running), but the connection will get refused. If I check the status again it'll be changed back to active(exited)